# jquery not working in dynamically loaded content

Tags: jquery

I have a page which has a few sections,now each section is hidden and shows when user clicks on it's link, I'm trying to use jquery .load to load these sections from external file so my page gets lighter, the problem is when I separate the sections from the main page and load them using .load, they load just fine with css and its just okay but no javascript is working inside the loaded content.
I have to use a few js files  for sections like my script, jquery UI , modernizer, easing &... etc.

I have all the js links in my main page just like css links but js doesnt work, I already  know that it is because content loads after js so when js is looking for elements there are no such things, So I'm looking for a way to tell it to look again when a section is clicked.
Thanks in advance for your help.

## Edit:

Let's say I have 5 js files, I have them all referenced in the main page, some of them only work in dynamically loaded content and some of them on main page and some on both, 
and I can't change js files for the dynamic content, 
So when I load content on a click function using.load is there any way to reset all the javascript to find loaded elemnts?

Comment: read jQuery docs FAQ. Situation is well documented

Comment: @charlietfl Can you please provide a link to this section?

Answer (score 2):

In case of event handlers you can simply use delegates. Instead of `$('.whatever').click(...);` you use this:

```
$('context_selector').on('click', '.whatever', ...);
```

`context_selector` needs to point to an element that exists the whole time while `.whatever` is the selector for your dynamically added elements.

Comment: ♦ the thing is using this solution I'll have to recode the whole script if I'm not mistaken, isn't there any way to reload javascript after the external content is loaded?

Comment: There is no good solution for it. And you just have to make a few changes anyway.

Comment: @ ThiefMaster♦ This is not duplicate, and your answer is good for that simple example and thats why I'm asking this question. please understand the question then try to use your power!

Comment: @Sonyflat: It *is* a duplicate. Actually I wouldn't have answered it at all if I had noticed this before.